# Why is my <a href> link not working inside this floating <div>?

Tags: html, css, css-float

I can't for the life of me figure out why a float:right  I have isn't showing hyperlinks properly. I was initially thinking it wasn't on the right z-index, but now I'm just confused. Is there a  that's blocking it somewhere?

The website address is [www.oakland-rotary.org](http://www.oakland-rotary.org)
I am referring to the purple vertical block at the top right of the website that starts off with "YOU ARE INVITED TO THE MAIN EVENT...". The text that is supposed to be hyperlinked is "CLICK HERE FOR INFO & TICKETS"

Here is the HTML code for that entire block area:

```
            <div id="leftcall" style="float:left;width:800px;">
            </div>
            <div id="rightcallout">

            <div style="margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;padding-bottom:10px;"><img src="/images/smallrotarylogo.png"></div>
            YOU ARE INVITED TO<br>
            <span style="font-size:34px;color:#f3d825;">THE MAIN EVENT</span><br>
            <br>
            <span style="font-family:arial;font-size:12px;">[ OUR ANNUAL FUNDRAISER ]</span><br>
            <span style="font-size:28px;color:#f3d825;">A MARDI GRAS PAR-TAY</span><br>
            AT ROCKWELL WINERY<br>
            IN ALAMEDA, CA<br>
            <br>
            <span style="font-family:arial;font-size:14px">March 1 from 6pm-10pm</span><BR>
            <BR>
            <span style="font-family:arial;font-size:14px;">
            <a href="http://www.eventbrite.com/e/a-mardi-gras-par-tay-oakland-rotary-3-rockwall-winery-march-1-2014-tickets-5268578460" target="_blank">CLICK HERE FOR INFO & TICKETS</a>
            </span>
            <br>                
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

And here is the CSS for that area:

```
#rightcallout {
float:right;
display:block;
z-index:9999;
height:100%;
width:200px;
padding:25px;
color:#fff;
font-family:League Gothic;
font-size:24px;
text-align:center;
background: #552baa; /* Old browsers */
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #552baa 0%, #5c2cb4 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#552baa), color-stop(100%,#5c2cb4)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #552baa 0%,#5c2cb4 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  #552baa 0%,#5c2cb4 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #552baa 0%,#5c2cb4 100%); /* IE10+ */
background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  #552baa 0%,#5c2cb4 100%); /* W3C */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#552baa', endColorstr='#5c2cb4',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
border-left:1px dashed #fff;
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you so much!!!

Comment: it seems to be working fine for me. It is in a very similiar color as the background, so it's not the easiest to see though.

Comment: I looked on your site, there is a div called <div id="frame"> which is in front of your other div. Your html is working: http://jsfiddle.net/txM3k/

Comment: You have an unnecessarily complex layout that results in two scrollbars in Chrome. I don't even see the text you mentioned, possibly because the scrollbar on that element is disabled. I'd try to simplify.

Comment: I also cannot see the text you mentioned which should be a hyperlink. The last portion I can see is "In Alameda, CA".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A this moment #rightcallout height it's bigger than available space.
I've change the font-size to auto... and content fits correctly.

```
#rightcallout {
float:right;
display:block;
z-index:9999;
height:100%;
width:200px;
padding:25px;
color:#fff;
font-family:League Gothic;
font-size:auto;  /* <<<-------- Modified*/
text-align:center;
background: #552baa; /* Old browsers */
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #552baa 0%, #5c2cb4 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#552baa), color-stop(100%,#5c2cb4)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #552baa 0%,#5c2cb4 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  #552baa 0%,#5c2cb4 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #552baa 0%,#5c2cb4 100%); /* IE10+ */
background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  #552baa 0%,#5c2cb4 100%); /* W3C */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#552baa', endColorstr='#5c2cb4',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
border-left:1px dashed #fff;
}
```

**For that link I made this:**

```
<span style="font-family:arial;font-size:14px;position: relative;z-index: 9999;">
<a href="http://www.eventbrite.com/e/a-mardi-gras-par-tay-oakland-rotary-3-rockwall-winery-march-1-2014-tickets-5268578460" target="_blank">CLICK HERE FOR INFO &amp; TICKETS</a></span>
```

I've tested in Chrome and works fine... hope this helps you.